# how to apply scss styles my CRA app with Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I made react app by CRA.
and I gonna use material ui and styling with SCSS.

[image]

I made main.css file by using node-sass.

and I tried to apply my main.css file to Material-ui Typography.

in main.css

```js
.logoTitle {
  font-size: 20rem;
}
```

But if loaded my web Typography element doesn't apply logoTitle styles..

what's my problem..?

Comment: Please put your code example in your question as text (as you did with the css) rather than as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is the same, the styles that are declared last in the CSS will win. By default, Material-UI places its styles at the end of the `<head>` element. This means that the default styles in Material-UI will win over other styles declared in the `<head>` with the same specificity (such as your `font-size` case). You can change this behavior by wrapping the top-level of your app with the `StylesProvider` element with the `injectFirst` property. This will cause Material-UI to place its styles at the beginning of the `<head>` element.

Here is a working example:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <Typography variant="h1" color="primary" className="logoTitle">
        Hello
      </Typography>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.logoTitle {
  font-size: 20rem;
}
```

[image: Edit StylesProvider injectFirst]

Related answer: [How to overwrite styles with classes and css modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827031/how-to-overwrite-styles-with-classes-and-css-modules/61828179#61828179)

Documentation: https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#stylesprovider

Comment: Thanks for your effort...! So kindness